# .Net 3.5 ORM that supports Medium Trust and POCOs

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, medium-trust

Scenario: I'm stuck with a shared hosting provider that runs in medium trust and has .Net framework 3.5

I've built a datalayer for my site using Nhibernate, only to discover that it can't run on medium trust.

I found some guides on the internet that explain to download Castle.Core and NHibernate sources and rebuild them allowing partial trust, but I'm runnin in all sort of problems (all sources got updated to .net 4.0, and although I know I can browse git repos for old commits, it seems like finding a needle in a haystack to me).

What I need now is an ORM that supports medium trust AND POCOs (so EF 1.0 and Linq to Sql are ruled out, as they are tightly coupled to their T4 generated classes).

I also got a "NO" from higher places about using Lightspeed ORM because it's limited to 8 tables for the free version and the schema might grow.

I know I am asking a lot, but if anyone knows an already built release of Nhibernate for 3.5 that can run in medium trust, or a valid alternative, I'd be more than happy.

Thanks.

Comment: you might wanna have a look at http://ormeter.net/

Comment: It doesn't mention anything about trust levels anywhere.

Comment: no-  but it shows you plenty of options.

Comment: I think chaning hosting provider may be you best option

Comment: I clearly stated that - sadly I might add - I'm stuck with this provider. Can't change it, I'm not the one deciding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently running a project with NHibernate 3.0 in a medium trust environment. I had to download the castle source and set `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` and then recompiled.

Everything then works perfectly. I am in the process of testing with 3.2 at the moment and will let you know the outcomes later this week.

I can ping you the modified DLL's if you like but please send me a dm on twitter. Use my SO name with the @ symbol.

I have also answered this [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825122/can-i-use-nhibernate-on-godaddy/4830626#4830626)

One other point, I would ask your hosting company to send you their modified medium trust policy file and then in your web config you reference it like:-

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Custom" policyFile="policy.config"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

This way you can test locally.

Comment: voted up your reply and removed mine: I'm a little worried about the not so exellent quality of the NH howto's

Comment: @Felice - I read this article loads of times and spent a long time working through this pain point! I should ask for permissions to upadte the article or create a howto on a blog!